# Solidity: Send a new contract ether in constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

I tried doing

```
address NewContract = new SomeTest.value(1 ether)();
```

But this yields a syntax error.

I try to call the payable constructor of a new contract with ether. What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: if using solidity version 0.7.x and later, you will need to use a slightly different syntax when passing value to a constructor.

Assuming that the name of the contract is SomeTest

**old method** - v0.6.x and earlier -

```
newContract = (new SomeTest).value(1 ether)();
```

**new method** - v0.7.x onwards -

```
newContract = (new SomeTest){value:1 ether}();
```

### UPDATE END

Try using the below syntax (ensure that the SomeTest constructor is marked **payable**):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SomeTest 
{
    constructor() public payable {}
}

contract A 
{
    address newContract;

    function test() public 
    {
      //construct a new SomeTest with 1 ether
      newContract = (new SomeTest).value(1 ether)();//works upto 0.6.x 
    }
}
```

Source: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#how-do-i-initialize-a-contract-with-only-a-specific-amount-of-wei

TLDR: encapsulate in parentheses like this **(new SomeTest).value(1 ether)** .

Comment: You can also do `newContract = new SomeTest{value:1 ether}();` here is the link updated https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=constructor#creating-contracts-via-new